# Image Uploading to onedrive "Error interpreting JPEG image file"

Tags: java, image, image-uploading, onedrive, okhttp

I did some sample uploads to OneDrive using graph api. I'm able to upload files(text files) successfully through OkHttp. But, when it comes to images i'm getting this message after opening image

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xef 0xbf)
```

after uploading image to onedrive. `.svg` format images are uploading successfully but `.jpg, .png` format images are corrupting when uploading to one drive.

The following is my way of approach

Converting the image to Byte array and then converting(writing) that Byte array to uploading file.

The code for converting image to byte array

```
byte[] contentBuilder = IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getObjectContent());
```

Code for uploading the byte array to onedrive as its original form.

```
String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root:/" + step.file_name + ":/content";

                        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                                .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), step.file_data))
        //step.file_data contains the byte array.
                                .addHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", step.getAccess_token()))
                                .build();
    Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

This approach is working for text files and .svg format images but not for other format images. I went through many references/websites but unable to find a way. What could be the reason!
Thank you :) in advance

Comment: Where is the code you use to read your file? Are your jpg and png files faulty or is this due to the way you read these files?

Comment: Added the code for reading file, The **jpg** and **png** images i'm using are downloaded from google and they are not faulty(verified in terminal _file image_name.png_ )

Comment: My advice is really to use a debugger and check when or even if the array gets corrupted. It's hart to tell if it's down to okhttp or the array here.

Comment: Yes i tried debugger too. Array size and its data is same(after converting image to array and while writing that array to file), uploading succesfully, but as a corrupted file. My doubt/confusion is why it is corrupting and is there any alternative to do that!

Comment: EF BF is the start of the BOM (Byte Order Mark), which strongly suggests that the file contents is being upload in Unicode instead of raw bytes. I'm no Java expert, but if I had to guess I'd suggest focusing on `RequestBody.create` and make sure it's not trying to generate a string based body.

Comment: @Brad yes, you are right. It is generating a String based body. I got the point, Thank you:)